# What is Level A and Level B in 3G SDI Interface

Tags: video

Can someone point me at a description of the difference between a 3G-Level A SDI signal and a 3G-Level B SDI signal.

Answer (score 0):

Level A carries a single 3G stream. Level B carries two 1.5G streams, whether a single dual-link stream, or two completely separate streams.

Comment: Is there any hardware changes required for this selection or is it taken care in software

Comment: Depends on the hardware. I don't know what hardware you are using and for what. You just asked about the difference between SDI levels.

Comment: Usually the hardware is the same, but the firmware running on the FPGA doing the business either needs to be different or at least put into a different mode. In practise there is not that much level B out there, it is in the standard, but a bit like the 32 channels of audio 'supported' on a 3G link, you are prone to disappointment if you plan to use it because an awful lot of kit will not be able to make sense of it.